# JDE EnterpriseOne Server Manager download only shows Disk1, not able to install on EnterpriseOne 9.2

Tags: jde, enterpriseone

Newbie here, trying to figure out JDE EnterpriseOne.
I am trying to setup the JDE EnterpriseOne Demo Platform so I can program and test web services (REST APIs) between Ignition and JDE.
JDE Orchestrator seems the way to go, but in order to install it, I need to install the EnterpriseOne Server Manager. I downloaded it from the edelivery, but the download has only Disk1 and doesn't install. I do not have an Oracle Support Contract.
Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you!

Unzipped the .zip file that can be downloaded, but it only has the Disk1 install, not the Disk2 that is mentioned in different posts.